# Segmentation Fault on using pointers instead of array

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

```
while(!feof(fname))
{       
    fscanf(fname,"%c",buf);
    printf("%c",*buf);
    buf++;
}
```

When I use this code, the compiler gives me a **segmentation fault(core dumped)**.
But instead of this if I use

```
int i = 0;
while(!feof(fname))
{       
    fscanf(fname,"%c",&buf[i]);
    printf("%c",buf[i]);
    i++;
}
```

This code runs fine, and the content of the file are read.
What am I doing wrong while incrementing the array pointer instead of using it as and array?
The whole code is

```
    FILE *fname;
    fname = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int i;
    char *buf;

    i=0;
    while(!feof(fname))
    {
    fscanf(fname,"%c",buf);
    printf("%c",*buf);
    buf++;

    }
    fclose(fname);
```

Comment: how and where is `buf` declared?

Comment: Need to see more code here.

Comment: Assuming its an array, shouldn't the first part be `fscanf(fname, "%s", buf);`?

Comment: @Jack: I'm betting something along the lines of `char *buf = "oh noes!;"` and `char buf[] = "I'm good";`

Comment: Post your entire code, specially the declarations.

Comment: Another bug: you *do* know that `while(!feof(fname))` does not do what you think it does? EOF is never set when the eof is reached, only when you attempted to read past the end of file. So for an empty file this will execute the loop body once with garbage.

Comment: Observation: most people seeing a variable `fname` somewhere near file handling code would expect that to be a file name (a string) and not a file stream.  The generic variable is `fp` (file pointer): `FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r"); if (fp == 0) ... report error...`.  The name `fd` should generally be reserved for a generic 'file descriptor' such as is returned by `open()`.  Your code isn't 'wrong'; it is just a little unorthodox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char *buf;`

This is a pointer and has no memory associated with it.

`fscanf(fname,"%c",buf);`

is attempting to place memory into this pointer.  It needs to either be `malloc`'d, or defined as a char array that won't overflow from the `fscanf()` input.

perhaps:

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 255
char buf[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
```

**Additional Info edit**

If you need a moving pointer, create a second one and use it:

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 255
char buffer_memory[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
char *buf = buffer_memory;
...
fscanf(fname,"%c",buf);
printf("%c",*buf);
buf++;
```

Until you read in 255 character at which point bad things happen.  If you don't know how big your file is beforehand (`ftell()`), then you will need to use a linked list system, a `realloc()` pattern, which is kinda icky, or a buffer that is guarenteed to be big enough to fit your file.

Comment: But, if I declare an array of characters with predefined size then I would have to use *(buf+i) and keep on incrementing i. I cant increment the pointer buf i.e buf++.

Comment: @vinit: but your pointer must point to somewhere that is safe for `fscanf()` to write to — and that means the pointer must be initialized and point to at least one character of space.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:That thing I understand. So, is there any way, I could use a "sliding pointer", instead of referring array??

Comment: @vinit: maybe...I'm not sure exactly what you're after, but one possibility might be `char buffer[100]; char *buf = buffer;` and then you can use `if (scanf(fname, "%c", buf) == 1) buf++;` to step one character at a time through `buf`.  Be careful to ensure you don't overflow the end of the underlying array (`buffer`).

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation in C is done with malloc(). If you don't know how many strings you might have, then you can't use an array (or a pointer simulating an array).  You'll have to allocate space for each string as it is read, and either add them to a linked list or re-allocate an array as it grows.